# Have all rows deleted by link/button click, and prevent it from auto executing

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with this code. I'd really like to delete all of the rows in a table just by the press of a link/button. In this case, there's a small "x" in the corner of the box where the message is displayed.

I've tried to set the href and onclick function to: *$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM ad");* But it somehow executes the command without pressing the "X" button. If I do remove the line from the code, it all works. (I do wish to have the delete function on the page I'm working on, and not to add a delete.php page for instance) Is there any solution for this problem?

```
<?php if($row_ad['type'] == 1){ ?>

    <div class="box error-box fx">
    <a class="close-box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    <center>
    <h3><?php echo $row_ad['title']; ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $row_ad['text']; ?></p></center>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What does your code have to do with your question?

Comment: The code is how the information/ad is displayed, and the "<a class="close-box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>" is where I wan't to press when I want to remove the row from the table.

Comment: There is a **lot** wrong here. First, `mysql_query` is deprecated. It will be removed from PHP in the future, you should not be using it and you should not waste your time learning to use it. Secondly, if you want to assign the query to the string, don't execute it it first, which is explicitly what `mysql_query` does. Just assign the *query* itself: `$query = 'DELETE FROM ad';`. Thirdly, if you want a link on your page to delete a table, you need to either use JavaScript to trigger a POST request, or embed a form which can issue the POST request for you. On POST-back execute the query.

Comment: The fact that they're removing mysql has been rumored for like 2-3+ years now. And the mysql lib is fine as it is. I'll just post it as  form, it'll be easier. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: *No*, it is not fine to use deprecated functions in new code. Full stop. Those functions are dead, don't use them. They have been deprecated since 5.5. We're now in 5.6, so of course they haven't removed them *yet*. Regardless, there are *far* better alternatives. Even if they never removed `mysql_*` functions, you *still* shouldn't use them.

Comment: I'm using dreamweaver as I have no advanced knowledge in PHP, nor MYSQL(mysqli?) and now it's kinda late to change 15 files with loads of MYSQL/PHP... Might take a look into it in the future.

Comment: It wouldn't be too late if you'd architected the pages properly. Going from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` or better yet, PDO, would involve one change in one place. Each of your pages should not be running their own queries in this way.

Comment: So I can basically replace all mysql_* to mysqli_* and have the page and function to work? Thought mysql has an different syntax, like: $conn -> query("Something something"); whereas mysql has $conn = mysql_query("something something"); ?

Comment: @Perelan - you can switch to `mysqli_` functions fairly simply. Most `mysql_` functions have an equivalent `mysqli_` function, though many of them require the connection variable as the first parameter, so `mysql_query($sql)` becomes `mysqli_query($connection, $sql)`

Comment: But bear in mind that one of the major advantages to `mysqli_` is being able to used prepared statements and bound variables, which can help make your code a lot safer and more efficient. To use those, you will have to do a little more re-writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is serverside and HTML/JS is client-side, the only way to do what you want is to look up AJAX;

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/